# cannot read "account name" from keychain using applescript

Tags: applescript

I am **not** able to read the "account name" from keychain using apple script.

this does not work:

```
tell app "Keychain Scripting" to get account of "app name"
```

I am able to read the password from keychain using the following:

```
local password
set password to do shell script ("security 2>&1 >/dev/null find-generic-password -gl " & quoted form of "app name" & " | cut -c 11-99 | sed 's/\"//g'")
```

is there a documentation on which commands to use for keychain scripting?

Comment: Keychain Scripting has been discontinued for a long time.

Comment: @CJK it gives this error:: Can’t get account of "app name".

Comment: @vadian what do you mean by that?

Comment: As far as I can remember Apple removed Keychain Scripting.app in Lion (macOS 10.7)

Comment: [_Usable Keychain Scripting_](https://red-sweater.com/blog/170/usable-keychain-scripting)